# phonegap sync with sql server

Tags: android, sql-server, sqlite, cordova, synchronization

I am developing Phonegap android application. In my Application user will enter the data and that data will be stored in sqlite database internally.
Now my Question
1. how can send all the data from sqlite database to sqlserver from phonegap application Or
2. Is there anyway to store data from phonegap to directly sql server database.

Answer (score 1):

I develop a plugin to do exactly right that, connect Cordova app directly to an external SQL Server data base. It's open source, here is the link https://github.com/SergioDosSantos/cordova-plugin-sqlserver.
You colud insert directly without any service.

Answer (score 0):

May be following links is useful to you:

[**PhoneGap Sample - Diary (Database and Camera support)**](http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2013/3/4/PhoneGap-Sample--Diary-Database-and-Camera-support)

**[Sample App using the PhoneGap Database API](http://coenraets.org/blog/2011/10/sample-app-using-the-phonegap-database-api/)**

**[Android PhoneGap MySQL Video Tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8IgEEhH-FsE)**

[**Posting data from a PhoneGap app to a server using jQuery**](http://samcroft.co.uk/2012/posting-data-from-a-phonegap-app-to-a-server-using-jquery/)

Keep Coding... :)

Answer (score 0):

**Answer to question 1** 
The only way to send data from your phonegap to the server is using AJAX calls. How you make the ajax call depends on which framework you are using. If it is JQuery, it can be a simple $.ajax call. That might change if you are using AngularJS or any Knockout.js.
If the amount of data to be transferred is large, a better approach is to use a sync plugin like this : https://github.com/orbitaloop/WebSqlSync or implement your own sync functionality.

**Answer to question 2**
The only way you can store data directly from phonegap to SQL Server database is by making ajax calls as soon as the data is ready to be saved. 
That could work in cases where the data is small, but could cause performance problems when the data is large.